# Ansible XML Array get elements inside an array

Tags: arrays, xml, get, ansible, element

I Have and Array of xmldocument obtained from a rest API.

```
<ArrayOfXmlDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <XmlDocument>
        <input xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:topology:pcep">
          .....
        </input>
    </XmlDocument>
  <XmlDocument>
        <input xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:topology:pcep">
          .....
        </input>
    </XmlDocument>
  <XmlDocument>
        <input xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:topology:pcep">
          .....
        </input>
    </XmlDocument>
</ArrayOfXmlDocument>
```

using Ansible I need to get  element and all the items inside input element and post to it to an API.

Just an example of input element:

```
  <input xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:topology:pcep">
            <node>pcc://7.188.102.54</node>
            <name>LSP--LAB--LAB/LSP--LAB--LAB-PRI</name>
            <arguments>
                <lsp xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:pcep:ietf:stateful">
                    <delegate>true</delegate>
                    <administrative>true</administrative>
                </lsp>
                <ero>
                    <subobject>
                        <loose>false</loose>
                        <ip-prefix>
                            <ip-prefix>10.10.12.2/32</ip-prefix>
                        </ip-prefix>
                    </subobject>
                    <subobject>
                        <loose>false</loose>
                        <ip-prefix>
                            <ip-prefix>10.10.26.2/32</ip-prefix>
                        </ip-prefix>
                    </subobject>
                </ero>
            </arguments>
            <network-topology-ref xmlns:topo="urn:TBD:params:xml:ns:yang:network-topology">/topo:network-topology/topo:topology[topo:topology-id="pcep-topology"]</network-topology-ref>
        </input>
    </XmlDocument>
```

This is my playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Check if service interface exists, fail if true and changes are not allowed
      xml:
        path: pcepxml.xml
        xpath: /ArrayOfXmlDocument/XmlDocument/*
        content: text
      #count: yes
      register: xmlresp
      #failed_when: doccount.count == 0

    - name: Print
      debug:
        var: xmlresp
```

tried `xmlresp.matches[0]`, `xmlresp.matches.XmlDocument` and other options but always obtain the following  output.

```
TASK [Print] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "xmlresp": {
        "actions": {
            "namespaces": {},
            "state": "present",
            "xpath": "/ArrayOfXmlDocument/XmlDocument/*"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "count": 24,
        "failed": false,
        "matches": [
            {
                "{urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:topology:pcep}input": "\n            "
            },
            {
                "{urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:topology:pcep}input": "\n            "
            },
...
        ],
        "msg": 24
    }
}
```

Which is the best option to get each input and post it to an API? the API only accept one input elemnent per call.

Thanks.

regards.

Comment: Jorge, some tips for posting... 1. Try to keep output short, reading can get tiring when there's lots of output. I've edited to help with this.

2. Be more clear about your question. I'm not clear on specifically what you're trying to call or what's wrong here.

Comment: Hi thanks PAL, I need to iterate an XML document with a lot of </input> each input is a call to another API, I consume an API iterate XML using Ansible and for each <input> i need to post to another API to process.  ODL (https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/user-guide/pcep-user-guide.html#lsp-state-synchronization-optimization-procedures)  ----  [link](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/user-guide/pcep-user-guide.html#id50) this parth specific

Answer (score 0):

Read the `xml` module docs carefully. Specifically I think the [return-xmlstring](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html#return-xmlstring) attribute will be of interest to you.

You'll be able to iterate over your registered result in later blocks.